# Unterminated quoted string in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am trying to print a loop in docker command shell. When I run the container in the first line, it seems it works as it executes the ID but when I print the logs, it shows "syntax error: unterminated quoted string"
I cannot find out what's wrong here? Can you help me please.

```
C:\Users\Anik Barua
λ docker run -d --name simple2 busybox /bin/sh -c 'i=0; while true; do echo ; i=1; sleep 1; done'
8bb4bfbe11f24f897ba66bb090e010eed24fd8cf1685e7c0a41b77abe34f864d

C:\Users\Anik Barua
λ docker logs simple2
while: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

C:\Users\Anik Barua
λ docker logs -f simple2
while: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

Answer (score 15):

Please check in your Dockerfile if there is any unterminated string. e.g.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/dockerdemo-1.0.jar]
```

instead of

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/dockerdemo-1.0.jar"]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! There was an error in my CMD statement's parameters.

Answer (score 8):

I was following this tutorial on setting a debezium structure to monitor changes in sql database.([debezuim tutorial](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.5/tutorial.html#starting-mysql-database))

```
docker run -it --rm --name mysqlterm --link mysql --rm mysql:5.7 sh -c 'exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"'
```

And the thing is to replace  the single quotes at the 'exec ...' with double quotes and it works fine.

Working version

```
docker run -it --rm --name mysqlterm --link mysql --rm mysql:5.7 sh -c "exec mysql -h"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR" -P"$MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT" -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ENV_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD""
```

Answer (score 6):

Your quoting is not correct, you should not use

`'`

But

`"`

Instead

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked now...  Can you please help me with another problem. Now, it seems that the program is running as the cursor is going to the next line but it is not showing the number in the console.

Comment: Your program does not echo anything, so it is normal it does not display anything, try `echo $i`